# During instantiation of class member: "no operator "[]" matches these operands" when accessing std::map value with map[key]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, stdmap, in-class-initialization

I have been looking at this for quite some time. I don't understand what is bothering it. The minimum code that is giving me the problem is shown bellow. I comment on the line where the error occurs. Compilation errors follow after the code.

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

template<std::size_t D>
class myclassA{
private:  
  std::array<std::string, D> a;
  std::map<std::string, std::size_t> a_type_num;
  std::array<std::size_t, D> a_dims;

  // used to initialize a_type_num
  inline std::map<std::string, std::size_t> return_type_dims() const{
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t> temp;
    for(auto const &s: a)
      temp.emplace(s, 0);
    for(auto const &s: a)     
      temp[s]++;
    return temp;
  };

  // used to initialize a_dims
  inline std::array<std::size_t, D> return_site_dims() const{
    std::array<std::size_t, D> temp;
    for(int i=0; i<D; i++)
      temp[i] = a_type_num[a[i]];  // ERROR!!!
    return temp;
  };

public:  
  // constructor
  myclassA(const std::array<std::string,D> &user) :  a(user)
    , a_type_num(return_type_dims())
    , a_dims(return_site_dims())
  {};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  myclassA<4> co({"d","d","p","p"});
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling I get the error:

```
src/main.cpp(32): error: no operator "[]" matches these operands
            operand types are: const std::map<std::__cxx11::string, std::size_t, std::less<std::__cxx11::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::string, std::size_t>>> [ const std::__cxx11::string ]
        temp[i] = a_type_num[a[i]];  
                            ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "std::array<std::size_t={unsigned long}, D> myclassA<D>::return_site_dims() const [with D=4UL]" at line 40
            instantiation of "myclassA<D>::myclassA(const std::array<std::__cxx11::string, D> &) [with D=4UL]" at line 45
```

On the other hand, something like this compiles fine (I mean the code is going to do nothing, but it compiles):

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  // myclassA<4> co({"d","d","p","p"});

  std::array<std::string, 10> a;
  std::map<std::string, std::size_t> a_type_num;
  std::array<std::size_t, 10> temp;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    temp[i] = a_type_num[a[i]];  

return 0;
```

So my question is: why is it complaining that `no operator "[]" matches these operands`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[]` operator requires a `std::map` that is not `const`, because its behaviour when it does not find the key is to modify the map by inserting the key. In your code, you have the `return_site_dims` method which is a `const` method, meaning that it only has `const` access to all the non-static members of the `myClassA` class, including the `a_type_num` map. Therefore, this method is not able to use the `[]` operator on that map. To fix this, you could make `return_site_dims` a non-`const` method.

Comment: Yah ok I was super dumb. Works fine after removing const, and this method should really not need to be const. The whole reason for it is to modify a class member.

Answer (score 2):

`return_site_dims()` is declared as a `const` method, so its `this` pointer is `const myclassA*`, and thus the `a_type_num` member accessed via that pointer is treated as a `const std::map` object.  However, `std::map` does not have an `operator[]` that can be called on a `const std::map` object, hence the compiler error.  A map's `operator[]` inserts a new entry if the requested key is not found, and it can't insert into a `const std::map` object.

You can use the map's [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) method instead, which has a `const` overload that does not insert missing keys, it throws `std::out_of_range` exceptions instead:

```cpp
inline std::array<std::size_t, D> return_site_dims() const{
  std::array<std::size_t, D> temp;
  for(int i=0; i<D; i++)
    temp[i] = a_type_num.at(a[i]); // <-- OK! exception if a[i] is not found...
  return temp;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the map's [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) method instead:

```
inline std::array<std::size_t, D> return_site_dims() const{
  std::array<std::size_t, D> temp;
  for(int i=0; i<D; i++) {
    auto iter = a_type_num.find(a[i]);
    if (iter != a_type_num.end())
      temp[i] = iter->second;
    else
      temp[i] = ...; // <-- some default value of your choosing...
  }
  return temp;
};
```

Comment: Yes find should have been what I used to begin with, since this is a helper method that should modify only `a_dim` and not `a_type_num`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it cannot work is that `return_site_dims` is declared as `const`, but `operator[]` is not a `const` method (it will modify the map if the element is not found). The only way to access a `const std::map` is using [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) or [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) if you want to have an exception instead of manual handling. So your loop could be rewritten:

```cpp
// used to initialize a_dims
std::array<std::size_t, D> return_site_dims() const {
  std::array<std::size_t, D> temp;
  decltype(a_type_num.end()) iter, iter_end = a_type_num.end();
  for (int i=0; i<D; i++) {
    iter = a_type_num.find(a[i]);
    if (iter == iter_end) {
      // HANDLE THIS SOMEHOW
    }
    temp[i] = *iter;
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Side comment: You don't need to declare `inline` functions `inline`, since functions written in the class declaration are automatically so.